# Fourier series of anti-periodic function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

If a function is antiperiodic so $f(x+\pi)=-f(x)$. What can be told about Fourier coefficients of that function on interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. What feature Fourier coefficients of that function has on interval.

I think that we can compute them like every odd function so we have only [bn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InJai.png) and $a_n = 0$. Is this correct way and how can I prove that?

Comment: If $f(x + \pi) = -f(x)$, then we have $f(x + 2\pi) = -f(x + \pi) = f(x)$ so the function is still periodic, just the period is double. You compute the Fourier coefficients the same way, just the formula for them is 'scaled' to account for the different period. Further, it is not true that all antiperiodic functions are odd. For example, $\cos{x}$ is $\pi$-antiperiodic since $\cos{(x + \pi)} = - \cos{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the complex form of the Fourier series for simplicity.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$ $$=\int_{-\pi}^{0} f(x)e^{-inx}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\pi} f(y-\pi)e^{-iny}e^{in\pi}dy+\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$ $$=[(1-(-1)^{n}]\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx.$$

Hence all the even coefficients are $0$. The converse is also true.